# Отправка почты со страницы контактов opencart 2.3

Tags: php, opencart

Есть стандартная форма отправки писем на почту на странице контактов в opencart 2.3, в итоге если человек заполняет форму email, то админу приходит письмо не от почты с домена сайта а от того какую почту там вписали
От: емейл человека который заполилнил
Тема: Письмо от Имя которое заполнили
Сообщение:
Сообщение

а надо стандартно, подскажите как сделать пожалуйста

От: почта сайта
тема: письмо от сайта
Сообщение:
Отправитель
Имя
Текст

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
        $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
        $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
        $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
        $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
        $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

        $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
        $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
        $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->setText(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        $mail->send();

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('information/contact/success'));
    }
```

Шаблон

```
  <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend><?php echo $text_contact; ?></legend>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
          <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
          <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_email; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-enquiry"><?php echo $entry_enquiry; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea name="enquiry" rows="10" id="input-enquiry" class="form-control"><?php echo $enquiry; ?></textarea>
          <?php if ($error_enquiry) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_enquiry; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo $captcha; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_submit; ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
// *    @copyright  OPENCART.PRO 2011 - 2017.
// *    @forum  http://forum.opencart.pro
// *    @source     See SOURCE.txt for source and other copyright.
// *    @license    GNU General Public License version 3; see LICENSE.txt

class Mail {
    protected $to;
    protected $from;
    protected $sender;
    protected $reply_to;
    protected $subject;
    protected $text;
    protected $html;
    protected $attachments = array();
    public $protocol = 'mail';
    public $smtp_hostname;
    public $smtp_username;
    public $smtp_password;
    public $smtp_port = 25;
    public $smtp_timeout = 5;
    public $verp = false;
    public $parameter = '';

    public function __construct($config = array()) {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }

    public function setTo($to) {
        $this->to = $to;
    }

    public function setFrom($from) {
        $this->from = $from;
    }

    public function setSender($sender) {
        $this->sender = $sender;
    }

    public function setReplyTo($reply_to) {
        $this->reply_to = $reply_to;
    }

    public function setSubject($subject) {
        $this->subject = $subject;
    }

    public function setText($text) {
        $this->text = $text;
    }

    public function setHtml($html) {
        $this->html = $html;
    }

    public function addAttachment($filename) {
        $this->attachments[] = $filename;
    }

    public function send() {
        if (!$this->to) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: E-Mail to required!');
        }

        if (!$this->from) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: E-Mail from required!');
        }

        if (!$this->sender) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: E-Mail sender required!');
        }

        if (!$this->subject) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: E-Mail subject required!');
        }

        if ((!$this->text) && (!$this->html)) {
            throw new \Exception('Error: E-Mail message required!');
        }

        if (is_array($this->to)) {
            $to = implode(',', $this->to);
        } else {
            $to = $this->to;
        }

        $boundary = '----=_NextPart_' . md5(time());

        $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;

        if ($this->protocol != 'mail') {
            $header .= 'To: <' . $to . '>' . PHP_EOL;
            $header .= 'Subject: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        $header .= 'Date: ' . date('D, d M Y H:i:s O') . PHP_EOL;
        $header .= 'From: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?= <' . $this->from . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        
        if (!$this->reply_to) {
            $header .= 'Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->sender) . '?= <' . $this->from . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $header .= 'Reply-To: =?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->reply_to) . '?= <' . $this->reply_to . '>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
        
        $header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . PHP_EOL;
        $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
        $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="' . $boundary . '"' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

        if (!$this->html) {
            $message  = '--' . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= $this->text . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $message  = '--' . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="' . $boundary . '_alt"' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

            if ($this->text) {
                $message .= $this->text . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                $message .= 'This is a HTML email and your email client software does not support HTML email!' . PHP_EOL;
            }

            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt' . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"' . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= $this->html . PHP_EOL;
            $message .= '--' . $boundary . '_alt--' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        foreach ($this->attachments as $attachment) {
            if (file_exists($attachment)) {
                $handle = fopen($attachment, 'r');

                $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachment));

                fclose($handle);

                $message .= '--' . $boundary . PHP_EOL;
                $message .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . PHP_EOL;
                $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . PHP_EOL;
                $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachment) . '"' . PHP_EOL;
                $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . urlencode(basename($attachment)) . '>' . PHP_EOL;
                $message .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ' . urlencode(basename($attachment)) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
                $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
            }
        }

        $message .= '--' . $boundary . '--' . PHP_EOL;

        if ($this->protocol == 'mail') {
            ini_set('sendmail_from', $this->from);

            if ($this->parameter) {
                mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header, $this->parameter);
            } else {
                mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($this->subject) . '?=', $message, $header);
            }
        } elseif ($this->protocol == 'smtp') {
            if (substr($this->smtp_hostname, 0, 3) == 'tls') {
                $hostname = substr($this->smtp_hostname, 6);
            } else {
                $hostname = $this->smtp_hostname;
            }

            $handle = fsockopen($hostname, $this->smtp_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->smtp_timeout);

            if (!$handle) {
                throw new \Exception('Error: ' . $errstr . ' (' . $errno . ')');
            } else {
                if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                    socket_set_timeout($handle, $this->smtp_timeout, 0);
                }
    
        
                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    //some SMTP servers respond with 220 code before responding with 250. hence, we need to ignore 220 response string
                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) == 220 && substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        $reply = '';
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    throw new \Exception('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                }

                if (substr($this->smtp_hostname, 0, 3) == 'tls') {
                    fputs($handle, 'STARTTLS' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 220) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error: STARTTLS not accepted from server!');
                    }

                    stream_socket_enable_crypto($handle, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT);
                }

                if (!empty($this->smtp_username)  && !empty($this->smtp_password)) {
                    fputs($handle, 'EHLO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error: EHLO not accepted from server!');
                    }

                    fputs($handle, 'AUTH LOGIN' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error: AUTH LOGIN not accepted from server!');
                    }

                    fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_username) . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 334) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error: Username not accepted from server!');
                    }

                    fputs($handle, base64_encode($this->smtp_password) . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 235) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error: Password not accepted from server!');
                    }
                } else {
                    fputs($handle, 'HELO ' . getenv('SERVER_NAME') . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error: HELO not accepted from server!');
                    }
                }

                if ($this->verp) {
                    fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>XVERP' . "\r\n");
                } else {
                    fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>' . "\r\n");
                }

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    throw new \Exception('Error: MAIL FROM not accepted from server!');
                }

                if (!is_array($this->to)) {
                    fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $this->to . '>' . "\r\n");

                    $reply = '';

                    while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                        $reply .= $line;

                        if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                        throw new \Exception('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ($this->to as $recipient) {
                        fputs($handle, 'RCPT TO: <' . $recipient . '>' . "\r\n");

                        $reply = '';

                        while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                            $reply .= $line;

                            if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ((substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) && (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 251)) {
                            throw new \Exception('Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server!');
                        }
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, 'DATA' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 354) {
                    throw new \Exception('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                }

                // According to rfc 821 we should not send more than 1000 including the CRLF
                $message = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $header . $message);
                $message = str_replace("\r", "\n", $message);

                $lines = explode("\n", $message);

                foreach ($lines as $line) {
                    $results = str_split($line, 998);

                    foreach ($results as $result) {
                        if (substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3) != 'WIN') {
                            fputs($handle, $result . "\r\n");
                        } else {
                            fputs($handle, str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $result) . "\r\n");
                        }
                    }
                }

                fputs($handle, '.' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 250) {
                    throw new \Exception('Error: DATA not accepted from server!');
                }

                fputs($handle, 'QUIT' . "\r\n");

                $reply = '';

                while ($line = fgets($handle, 515)) {
                    $reply .= $line;

                    if (substr($line, 3, 1) == ' ') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (substr($reply, 0, 3) != 221) {
                    throw new \Exception('Error: QUIT not accepted from server!');
                }

                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
```

Замените на:

```
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
```

Comment: угу, вся проблема была в том что я не чистил кэш) и долго думал что надо копать в другом файле)

Answer (score 1):

В общем решил пока сам так. В contact.php сделал так выдает теперь как надо

```
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf('Сообщение от сайта'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $message='Почта: '.$this->request->post['email']."\n\n Имя: ".$this->request->post['name']."\n\n Сообщение: ".$this->request->post['enquiry'];
    $mail->setText($message);
    $mail->send();
```